# How to dynamically fill dialog with view objects?

Tags: java, android, dynamic, dialog, adapter

I am trying to create a class that creates very dynamic dialogs for my Android application.

These are examples of the dialogs I want to create:

[image: Example of my application]

What I need is a dynamic dialog creator. When I have a list with View objects (buttons (all with different click methods) and a title), I want to pass the list to a method that builds a dialog and shows it.

My question is: how can I make these dynamic dialogs ?

I thought of using an adapter to fill the dialogs with the view objects, but that doesn't look possible?

What do I have so far?

[image]

The code for this (not dynamic) dialog :
overlay.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/overlay_master_view">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:padding="10dp"
           android:id="@+id/linie"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:background="@drawable/tile_button_wordtile">

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Menu"
               android:padding="5dp"
               android:textColor="@color/white"
               android:background="@color/transparant"
               android:layout_margin="10dp"/>


           <Button
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:padding="5dp"
               android:layout_margin="10dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:textColor="@color/white"
               android:background="@drawable/tile_button_functiontile"
               android:text="Annuleren"/>

       </LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

OverlayManager.java:

```
 public static void onCoachMark(Activity c){
        dialog = new Dialog(c);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.overlay);

        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        //for dismissing anywhere you touch
        View masterView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.overlay_master_view);
        masterView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: What about using an external library?

Comment: What external library?

Comment: Here you can find a bunch of them: http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/09/dialog-libraries-for-android-project.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend a `DialogFragment` and override the `onCreateView` method

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, container, false);
    return v;
}
```

and finally display it using

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
if (prev != null) {
    ft.remove(prev);
}
ft.addToBackStack(null);
DialogFragment newFragment = new YourDialogFragment();
newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
```

more info - [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)